# How do i reposition my previous slick arrow to become operable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently creating my webpage using HTML/CSS with the addition of Javascript slick slider. I am currently using the regular slider code for my gallery tab, however, my previous arrow button (.slick-prev:before) is submerged behind my div class "slider_1", with my .slick-next:before arrow working how it should be comfortably sitting outside of the div.

I have added margin and padding to .slick-prev:before however it only pushes the arrow further out of sight within the div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Photography</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    
<style type="text/css">
    html, body 
    {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .slick-slide 
    {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before
    {
      color: black;
    }

    </style>
</head>`



`<div class="slider_1">
        <div><img src="twitter.png" width="400px" height="400px">Photo1</div>
        <div><img src="twitter.png" width="400px" height="400px">Photo2</div>
        <div><img src="twitter.png" width="400px" height="400px">Photo3</div>
        <div><img src="twitter.png" width="400px" height="400px">Photo4</div>
    </div>

    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider_1').slick({
        dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I would like to be able to have my previous arrow outside of the slider div to become operable. as currently the arrow simply sits behind my images inside the slider not serving any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding:**
Having read your question, I feel your experiencing layer problems, in that your next and previous buttons are hidden behind other web elements.

**Solution:**
We can write some CSS that tells it to alter the layer position to a higher layering number, to do this we use CSS using the  **Z-Index** property and assign a high number such as 99 to ensure it sits above all other elements on the webpage.

To use z-index we **must** specify a **position** property with the value of fixed, absolute or relative.

In my example, I have used the relative value, so that it doesn't tamper with where the arrows were originally positioned.

**Code to try:**

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next{
      position: relative;
      z-index:99 !important;
 }
```

However, if you find that the code only affects 1 of your sliders, then you might want to add an ID to the sliders HTML and write your CSS as follows:

```
#slider_1.slick-prev, #slider_1.slick-next{
      position: relative;
      z-index:99 !important;
 }
```

Then alter the affected slider's HTML to have the ID in it also

```
<div class="slider1" id="slider1">
```

Comment: Thank you very much DataCure this amended code has work with great results. Having just done some minor research on z-index i have gained a  better understanding of where my problems were.